# Get NetSuite transaction data based on item filter for journals with null ITEM_ID?

Tags: netsuite

How do I get transaction data based on an item filter for journals with null ITEM_ID? I'm a database guy not a finance guy and my finance people can pull a report from NetSuite that shows each transaction with posting period, filtered by item. I'm unable to do the same because the Transaction_Lines table has null ITEM_ID's for the entries I'm looking for, presumably because they are journal entries. This particular ITEM_ID is not in the Transaction_Lines table at all so I'm assuming that's because it's always handled by journal entries. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post an MVC of your query so that we can help?

Comment: What is an MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being to point to the Revenue_Plans, Revenue_Plan_Lines, and Revenue_Elements table but I had to be careful to join to the posting period rather than the planned period. Then I could do two select queries, one for journals and one for all other income types.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're referring to the NetSuite.com Data Source querying via ODBC. If this is correct, I believe that you're looking for the "Posting_account_activity_pe" table, which should contain all journal transactions, whether or not they have an Item_ID associated with them:

[image: SQL Query for Table]

More details can be found on the Connect Browser:

https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2020_1/odbc/record/posting_account_activity_pe.html

Comment: Thanks but the amounts in the posting_account tables don't line up with what my accounting team is getting directly out of NS.